# Freeform Pro Notify User select menu is blank

Tags: solspace-freeform

When I check the enable box form my 'Notify User' form preferences, the drop down is blank.   Any idea what I need to check/code wise or other in order to get the list of fiends to appear in this drop down menu?
We're using EE2.9.2 and Freeform Pro v.4.2.2

Also, and I figure the answer is no but will ask anyway.
In either the admin_notify or admin_cc_notify parameters, can you use multiple email addresses, with one being a field/variable from the form itself?

So if the form contained the field email2 which is an email address.  Could the admin_cc_notify field = "email2"?

Thanks

Peter T

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add an email field to the form before you can get a field to choose for user notification emails.

Admin notification emails can only be directly set on the parameter and cannot be set via a field. You can also set it in the form preferences in the control panel.

If you need additional notification types, there are the dynamic recipients:

https://solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#recipients

Which let you specify a hidden list of emails, chosen by the user with a key that posts and selects the hidden email (this helps to prevent spam) or you can use a user inputted email notification via user recipients:

https://solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#recipient_user_input